# GAE Datastore - entity field is momentarily empty

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, transactions, jdo

I'm using GAE, Java, JDOv3, GWT.

Here's my problem: 
I have a class Person and a class Food, they looks as follows:

Person:

```
public class Person
{
   .
   . id stuff here
   .

   @Persistent(mappedBy = "parentPerson")
   List<Food> favoriteFoods = new ArrayList<Food>();
}
```

Food:

```
public class Food
{
   .
   . id stuff here
   .

   @Persistent
   Person parentPerson;
}
```

Now if I make a query to retrieve all the Persons I will retrieve all the Foods too (I make sure to 'touch' the favoriteFoods-list (so it gets retrieved). This works all great.

BUT, if I decide to update one Food entity belonging to a Person entity and then straight after retrieves all Person-entities, sometimes, for some milliseconds (100ms->2sec), the favoriteFoods field in the Person-class is empty according to the datastore-viewer (and when actually checking the list in code). This doesn't sound like a big deal, but imagine a person accessing the Person-object and then re-saves it to the datastore, when it has a list of favoriteFoods as empty. It will overwrite the existing list with an empty one.

I would accept this as an acceptable behaviour if I actually retrieved a favoriteFoods-list that contained the last known data, but that isn't the case. Instead I get an empty list momentarily? If I keep refreshing the datastore-viewer (or in code) the list will eventually get the correct values (some millisecs).

I'm retrieving the Person-entities by doing the following:

```
PersistenceManager pm = PMF.getPersistenceManager();
Query query = pm.newQuery(Person.class);
List<Person> persons = (List<Person>) query.execute();
//Some 'touching'
persons = (List<Person>) pm.detachCopyAll(persons);
```

And saving the entity by doing the following:

```
pm.makePersistent(entity);
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Like many people using GAE, not looking at the log really doesn't help your situation. It shows contact with the datastore (when you look at DEBUG level), and from that you can conclude where the "issue" is, perhaps in "eventual consistency" strangeness of the datastore?

Comment: Not quite sure I understand what you are saying (sorry). Are you telling me to look at the logs or post the logs here or both? In either case, more exactly, what am I looking for? I did "log" stuff by printing out the contents of the favoriteFoods-list, but it is indeed empty when retrieved directly after a change to a Food-entity in the list. :/

Comment: Your JDO persistence has a log (like the vast majority of software does). This particular logged info is created to help _you_ with your persistence work. It's not about what _you_ logged yourself, but what the persistence process logged. You should start your debugging by looking at that log (at DEBUG level, as already said) ...

Comment: Thank you! I will look into this immediately!

Comment: I now got tons of logs to look at, but I'm not sure what I'm looking for. If I post them here, would you mind just fast-read through them and see if you find anything suspicious?

Comment: You refer to persisting something, so look at the log part for that, that the persist goes to the DB (datastore access). Then you refer to a query, so look where the object comes from (datastore access). If it is simply a case of delay in the query being given the updated data, then the problem is in the datastore, so read up on "eventual consistency"

Comment: Thank you once again, I will try to use this to locate the error. I know that there is "eventual consistency", but that shouldn't mean the existing data should be removed for a split second, it should show the "old" data.